# Bioperl: notes or online references for beginners

Tags: perl, bioperl

Please suggestion, I want to get started from 0. I do have experience on R.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the documentation available at http://www.bioperl.org ?  I found a HOWTO for beginners, and installation instructions for various platforms.  If you're looking to learn perl, try http://www.perl.org/books/library.html for some free online textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

The book [Mastering Perl for Bioinformatics](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003074.do?green=8934751471&cmp=af-mybuy-978059...) has a [chapter](http://oreilly.com/catalog/mperlbio/chapter/ch09.pdf) on BioPerl.  That chapter is available as a sample from Oreilly.